# Adding drop shadow to table view cell

Tags: swift

I am trying to add a drop shadow to a table cell but can't seem to get it to work.

I was able to successfully do it to a UIView in a scrollview using:

```
myStatsView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
myStatsView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1)
myStatsView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
myStatsView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```

But I have updated my app for Swift 2 and decided to use table view instead of scrollview.

I tried adding the cell content view as an outlet but nothing seems to work.

Is it even possible to add shadows in between table cells? I don't want all cells to have a shadow, just some.

Thanks

Comment: I think it is because of the cell has maskToBounds true. Try to set it to false. You can do it in interface builder by unchecking the clip subview item of the cell.

Comment: maskToBounds fixed it however I now have another odd thing happen. When the view first loads the drop shadow is applied to the bottom of the cell only (great!). But when the top of the cell scrolls out of view and then back in, the drop shadow is applied to both top and bottom. How can I keep it only to the bottom of the cell?

Answer (score 11):

I used different technique to add drop shadow to table cell. I add one `UIView` into the cell and add other controls like `UILabel`, `UIImageView` into that view and give the drop shadow to that view. Bellow is the code

```
self.viewBg!.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
self.viewBg!.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
self.viewBg!.layer.shadowRadius = 4
self.viewBg!.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
self.viewBg!.layer.masksToBounds = false;
self.viewBg!.clipsToBounds = false;
```

In above code `viewBg` is IBOutlet object.