# SWIFT UITableViewCell with corner radius and shadow

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I've been trying to create a custom tableview cell with rounded corners and drop shadow, I managed to create the rounded corners but the shadow is showing only on the corners and no where else.

Answer (score 13):

For both the shadow and the rounded corners, you can use this code:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UICollectionView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
     cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
     let shadowPath2 = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.bounds)
     cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
     cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
     cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: CGFloat(1.0), height: CGFloat(3.0))
     cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
     cell.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath2.cgPath
     return cell
 }
```

And you can adjust the values and you'll get the perfect shadow for you!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

seems like UITableviewCell doesnt support drop shadows. [Adding drop shadow to table view cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730803/adding-drop-shadow-to-table-view-cell), please take a look at this.